# IBM Websphere MQ displays javax.jms.TextMessage as <RFH >

Tags: java, queue, jms, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty

I am sending message from Java Code to `Websphere MQ Server` and when I am reading the same message on MQ server, it's displaying as:

```
message<RFH >
```

Below is the code sending the message to MQ server:

```
private void sendMessage() throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory cf1 = (ConnectionFactory) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jms/wmqCF");

        // Lookup Queue resource from JNDI
        Queue queue = (Queue) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jms/wmqQ1");
        Connection con = cf1.createConnection();

        // start the connection to receive message
        con.start();

        // create a queue session to send a message
        Session sessionSender = con.createSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        MessageProducer send = sessionSender.createProducer(queue);

        TextMessage msg = sessionSender.createTextMessage("Liberty Sample Message");

        // send a sample message
        send.send(msg);

        if (con != null)
            con.close();
        System.out.println("Send Message Completed");
    }
```

Expected to be displayed as: `Liberty Sample Message`.

Any idea, what I am missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the **`targetClient="MQ"`** as a property of `jmsQueue` works.

Below is the configuration change in `server.xml` of [WLP](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/websphere-liberty/):

```
<jmsQueue id="jms/queue1" jndiName="jms/wmqQ1">
    <properties.wmqJms baseQueueManagerName="QMA" baseQueueName="QUEUE1" targetClient="MQ"/>
</jmsQueue>
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you retrieve the message with another JMS program then the message data will be "Liberty Sample Message".

You are mixing JMS and non-JMS program types.

> .lookup("java:comp/env/jms/wmqQ1");

Set the 'TARGCLIENT' attribute to MQ.  i.e. TARGCLIENT(MQ)

Then the message data will not have the RFH2 header.

Comment: My Queue is of type `javax.jms.Queue` not of `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue`, so it's not having an option to set `TARGCLIENT `.